# AcePC AK2 power fan without fan connector

Tags: power-supply, fan, minipci

I have a ACEPC AK2 small computer and the fan works, but the terminal to the motherboard is destroyed.

The entire terminal ripped of taking some of the pcb with it.

Is there any where on the board that I could run some wires to get enough power to power the fan?

I thought that maybe if I run some wires directly to the barrel connector, but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: Replacement on ebay is $140>>>>https://www.ebay.com/itm/234566919755

Comment: Yeah not worth my money, the computer is honestly pretty crappy, but I had it lying around. I was just trying to fix it as an opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Ripping off the fan terminal may well have done more damage than you realize.

Your description of how you might fix it does not leave warm fuzzy feelings (yes, I fix electronic gear). You most likely need a circuit diagram to determine the path of the missing traces.

Take it to a local computer service shop and see if they think they can repair it, or if it is beyond repair and the small computer needs to be replaced.

Ultimately it may be simpler to just replace the computer.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but I understand it probably is. I don't need this small computer for anything major. I was just trying to get it working as a project. I don't need the fan controlls or anything, so I would be fine with it being 100% all the time, but I'll see if I can find a half decent repair shop near me. I just moved, so I don't know anything/anyone in the area.

Comment: You may be able to get someone experienced to show you how to hook up the wires from fan to computer. That will help you along your way.

Comment: If you don't take issue with the fan running 100% persistently, I don't see what the issue is with directly powering the fan from an alternate power source?  I've seen similar cases with recycled/upcycled builds where people would even use a spare PSU specifically to power a fan.